# Why C# Sendkeys not working for Control+L?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm using `SendKeys.SendWait("+(l)");` for sending Ctrl+L, but it does not work. I tried '+l', '+(L)', +{L} but none of them are working. What may be the cause?

Comment: `SendKeys.SendWait("^(l)")`

Comment: Falco Alexander, Thanks a lot it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^(l)")
```

Comment: @nawala Please mark this as correct answer by clicking the "check" button left of the answer, You will then get 2 points, and Falco will get 15 points.